# Polynomial-Exponential Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, polynomials, exponential-function

Consider the following sequences $$   x_n = \sup \{ k \in \mathbb{N} : e^{2^k} 2^k \leq n     \} $$  $$  y_n = \sup \{ k \in \mathbb{N} : e^{2^k} 2^{2k}   \leq n   \} $$
Clearly $x_n \geq y_n$ but I would like to show that infact $x_n=y_n$ for all sufficiently large $n$. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is blatantly and obviously **false**. (It may be *asymptotically* true in some sense, but that's another story.)

Say, $a_k=e^{2^k} 2^k$, and $b_k=e^{2^k} 2^{2k}$. Now it is rather obvious that $a_1<b_1<a_2<b_2<a_3<b_3\dots$, where every "<" contains a pretty wide interval including many natural numbers. Well, for every $n$ such that $b_k<n<a_{k+1}$ you will have $x_n=y_n=k$, but then there are many other numbers such that $a_k<n<b_k$, and for them it will be $x_n=k,\;y_n=k-1$.

Comment: Thanks so much. I was wondering if you could perhaps clarify what you ment about being asymptotically true?. Also, if I understand your proof right, this actually shows that they deviate by at most +1 ?

Comment: Well, maybe if we check all $n<N$, we'll find out that the _fraction_ of those having $x_n=y_n$ asymptotically tends to 1 as $N\to\infty$. As for the deviation by at most 1: yes, that's right.